# Manipulação de dados em excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-excel

Eu preciso pegar os dados gerados de uma `proc` salvar em alguma variável que seja e fazer um `UPDATE` em uma planilha já existente em um caminho fixo no sistema. É possivel fazer esse processo via código ?

Ex.
A procedure me retornou esses dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu precisaria armazenar esses dados em algum lugar e dar um `UPDATE`
em uma planilha ja criada que vai ficar fixa em um determinado caminho.

Comment: UPDATE em planilha??? Você quer alterar os dados dessas planilha? Poste algumas linhas da planilha e mostre como quer que os dados recebidos da procedure alterarem os dados da planilha.

Comment: Nesse caso então você quer passar essas informações geradas da **procedure**, para um (xml, json ou etc.) e criar uma nova planilha com esses dados pra substituir a planilha fixa?

Comment: @Mr_Ghost Na verdade seria passar as informações geradas da procedure e fazer um insert em um planilha já existente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de código para atualizar uma planilha em Excel com C# e ADO:

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = @"c:\dev\tmp\consolidated.xlsx";
connectionStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
connectionStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;");

using (var connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    var updateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    updateCommand.CommandText = "update [second$] S inner join [first$] F on S.ID = F.ID set S.Language = F.Language";
    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Crédito para a [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385528/how-to-update-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp)

Comment: `+1` A utilização do ADO é a mais recomendada

Comment: @Alexandre Cavaloti, teria como utilizar dados gerados de uma procedure e aplicar os mesmo com parametro pra fazer um insert na planilha ?

Comment: Sim, basta abrir uma conexão com o banco de dados para chamar a procedure, guardar o resultado e aplicar na solução acima.